# apache 2.4 followsymlinks behaves differently in a world writable directory

Tags: apache

Consider the following example directory structure

```
/htdocs
   /staff
      /firstname.lastname
         index.html
      login -> firstname.lastname
```

In the apache config we have

```
 <Directory "/var/www/htdocs/staff">
     Options             +FollowSymLinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
 </Directory>
```

Assume that the directory staff is owned by a different user then the
symlink. Now if the directory staff is world writable a request
for /staff/login will produce a

```
  Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/htdocs/staff/login
```

If the directory is not world writable the request succeeds.
So to be precise

```
drwxrwxrwt+ root wwwgrp /var/www/htdocs/staff
lrwxrwxrwx+ user root   /var/www/htdocs/staff/login -> firstname.lastname
```

and the + indicates an acl, which gives read access to the userid running the apache daemon. In this case it fails. If we change staff to

```
drwxrwxr-t+ root wwwgrp /var/www/htdocs/staff
```

it works.
If the owner of the link matches the owner of the parent directory staff, it works in both cases. We then have

```
drwxrwxrwt+ user wwwgrp /var/www/htdocs/staff
lrwxrwxrwx+ user root   /var/www/htdocs/staff/login -> firstname.lastname
```

and the acl is unchanged.

All this is irrespective of the owner of the target directory as long as the directory and the index.html file are readable for the apache daemon.

How can this be explained ? This does not seem to agree with the documentation on FollowSymLinks.
Leaving out the  -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch from the apache config makes no difference.

Ben

Comment: Can you add namei -m on the link and its target in a pastebin? I can't get the behavior.

Comment: added the information inline